# ui router dynamic URL issue - url: '/:id/page1' not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

How to create dynamic route when using ui router,

if we define:

```
$stateProvider.state('page1', {
      url: '/page1/:id',
      views:{}
}
```

It works fine,

But if we try to add dynamic id first and then page name then it gives error,

**ERROR:**

```
$stateProvider.state('page1', {
      url: '/:id/page1',
      views:{}
}
```

How to resolve this issue, can anyone help me into this?

Comment: That should work just fine. Can you share some more code? Like how are you transitioning into the page1? With a button or something?

Comment: How to fix it in routing?

Comment: using simple link, like <a href="pages/page1">page1</a>  Here pages is dynamic, sometime its page, home or anything else but page1 is fixed.

Comment: actually its menu and sub menu part, sub-menu can come under any main menu.

Comment: Ok I now understand your problem and provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based on your comment you should use something like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('page1', {
  url: '/:id/page1'
});
```

The part above was just fine. But in your link you should use something like this:

```
<a ui-sref="page1({id: '1234'})">page1</a>
```

You can also set a variable to the `ui-sref` like:

```
<a ui-sref="page1({id: page.id})">page1</a>
```